# I want to select some of item to stay at the top of my list view builder( like pining chats in whatsapp). How to implement this feature?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to select some of item to stay at the top of my list view builder( like pining chats in telegram). How to implement this feature?

Answer (score 1):

You can just rearrange that list with putting that item on top. Just do this

```
dynamic item = list.removeAt(index);
list.insert(0, item);
```

remove the item from your list and add it in the first, here you will get index from the `ListView.builder`
And do an `setState((){})` so show the rearrange list in the UI.

Comment: thank yu..but when the  new item will be  added in listview builder the pinned item moving from the top position..i want to stay the pinned item on top for forever

Comment: As of my thinking i'm not aware of any kind of pre-built functions you can use. For now you have another list where you just add the pinned items. First you will show pinned item list and after that your normal items list.